# Android muliple WebView save instance

Tags: android, webview

I try to save and restore the state of 3 `WebViews` in my activity by using `onSaveInstanceState()` and the `restoreState()` method of my `WebView` in `onCreate()`. This works just fine when I had only one `WebView`, but with 3 `WebViews` to save, it looks like it's only the last one save which counts and overrides the other saves; and so when I use the `restoreState()` method in `onCreate()`, the first `WebView` has the content of the third `WebView` and the 2 others are empty.

Here is a sample of my activity code:

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1)).saveState(outState);
  ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview2)).saveState(outState);
  ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview3)).saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview2)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview3)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Should I use some trick to use another bundle for each view? Have I done something wrong somewhere else in my code that causes this or is it the standard behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 2nd call of `saveState()` overwrites the contents saved in the first call and the 3rd call overwrites the content of the 2nd call. At the end of the execution of `onSaveInstanceState()` the bundle only contains the 3rd `WebView`'s state.

This is why when you restore the state of the 3rd `WebView` gets restored to the 1st `WebView`.

Create a new bundle object of each of your `WebViews` and put them into the outState `Bundle` object using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putBundle%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) giving a different key for each `Bundle`:

```
public void putBundle (String key, Bundle value)
```

In `onCreate()` get the `Bundle`s based on the 3 keys and restore the states.

Comment: I have a realted issue. I have one webview in each of the tabs in my tabview. In that case how to save. Even if i save using different keys, its only one value that is getting repeated evrytime.