# WebView SaveInstanceState for multiple WebViews

Tags: android, webview

I am using two webViews and I want to save and restore the state of this 2 webViews using onSveInstanceState().

Trying this the state was overwriting:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView1.saveState(savedInstanceState);
    webView2.saveState(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView1.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    webView2.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I found a possible solution, but I don't understand, maybe someone could explain it more detail or post some code: [Android muliple WebView save instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172800/android-muliple-webview-save-instance)

Greetings